# UnknownHostException in Unix while using InetAddress.getByName()

Tags: networking, unix, java, command-line-interface

I use this snippet of Java code to lookup an IP Address from the domain name

```
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("google.com");
```

It works fine in Windows & Linux but throws `java.net.UnknownHostException` in Unix.

For `nslookup google.com`, I am getting "No address information is available" in console.
How can I resolve it ?

Comment: Verify that DNS resolution is working properly first. As your `netstat` output suggests, it's not. Which Unix are you talking about?

Comment: You have an answer below, but this question is really off-topic for Server Fault - per the [FAQ] all questions here are supposed to relate to professional system administration in some way - there's no indication from your question that this question is related to professional system administration, and while we don't discourage basic questions this one is a little below the minimum barrier to entry...

Answer (score 2):

If your server has Internet connectivity, you will need to add a nameserver in your `/etc/resolv.conf` file

```
       nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

You can also replace 8.8.8.8 with our own dns server, if you have any.